# Jenkins multi-configuration job for script synchronization

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm currently using jenkins with clustered slaves.

There is a multi-configuration job (triggered by a git hooks), which do nothing, it purpose is just to pull a git repository on all slaves. This repository stores all the needed scripts for other jenkins jobs. Thank to this, we can update the job's build script through git and ease the maintenance of our jenkins instance (I'm the only one familiar with Jenkins, and so setup this mess for my team).

However, the scripts aren't pulled in the same place on each slave:
In two slaves, the repository is pulled in `/builds/workspace/<multi-configuration job's name>/label/<slave's name>` and `/builds/workspace/<multi-configuration job's name>`.
In the last slave, the repository is only pulled in `/builds/workspace/<multi-configuration job's name>/label/<slave's name>`.

So, I have two questions :

- Is it a good idea to use such multi-configuration job to synchronize build scripts in all the slave ?
- Why the multi-configuration job doesn't pull the repository in the same place for all slaves ?

About the configuration:

The source code management and build triggers are configured to allow triggering from git hooks (`Poll SCM` is checked).
There is no build step.

Here is the configuration matrix:

[image: configuration matrix]
(The master node is unchecked)

Comment: kindly share the configuration.. if used it it build step it should sync in same place..

Comment: @DevD There is almost nothing in the configuration :/ I edited and add the configuration matrix, but feel free to ask if others information are relevant :)